# How to differentiate between two or more devices in the same ip address (wifi)?

Tags: file, mobile, wifi, p2p

I am currently working on networking project that share files between mobile devices using p2p technology. Using wifi or mobile network. The main problem is when using wifi the general ip address become the same for all connected devices to that wifi connection and this is the problem how to send the file to a particular one if all connected devices have the same ip address?

Comment: What do you mean by general IP address?? Every device under same network will have distinct private IP address. There should not be any problem to distinguish. By saying general IP address do you mean the public address of that network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every device on same network has private IP addresses which are unique. All of them shares one public IP address. Now how do server distinguish them by only seeing their public IP and send them data?

Well the answer is the server doesn't see only IP address. It sees IP:Port. Every private IP connected to the server has same public IP but different port. The public IP belongs to your [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Your NAT assigns unique port to every private IP addresses and maps them. The mapping is like this [private IP, private port, public IP, public port, transport protocol].

So when your server sends a packet to public IP:port then the packet is forwarded to the mapped private IP:port. And your device with that private IP:Port receives it.

Comment: Thank you .. that was wonderful .. you will see my app soon .. 

Answer (score 0):

Use the `mac` address which is uniques for every device you pick.

Comparing `mac` address will be easy when you encounter multiple devices with same IP address.

Comment: It will lead to more problems. It is easy to change the mac address and is it possible to attach the mac address to the ip address and send the file?

Comment: Actually, The connected devices in the same network will not have the same ipaddress. So, Pl. review the address you are refering to on every device. It might happen if you are testing incorrectly, i.e on same computer/device.

Comment: True, yet you can block a device from using the wifi network and replace the local ip address with other device and this a big risk where the file will be in others hands whether it is encrypted or not.

Comment: If you can explain to me how whatsapp server tell who is the one should receive the message from others connected to the same network?  i will be glad to know.

Comment: whatsapp is a client-server architecture and not p2p architecture. Periodic heart beats are sent from client to the centralized whatsapp server which looks for any new messages that it is received. If you don't have an active internet connection on wifi router and you wan't to send a whatsapp message to your someone connected to same wifi - You won't be able to because the app is unable to contact the centralized whatsapp server.

Comment: I don't know for sure how whatsapp server knows who to send message but I can guess. Whats app server knows the public IP address:port of every users connected to it. So the server sends packet to the public IP:address port of the user and the NAT forwards it to that users private IP address:port.

Comment: Okay, but this could work for one device for one public ip .. how about up to seven devices connected to the same wifi and shareing the same public ip address. I know this is possible since it is working for every body .. i am using stack overflow app using my wifi and also my laptop and the data wanted by the phone go to the phone and so on .. i just need some information about it .. i don't know from where I can start .. i need to finish my app.